# Drawing a root-less graph of nodes with shared children

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

My aim is to produce a graph as illustrated by the code below: ( I am not yet allowed to post pictures)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]
        \node [circle,draw](a){XY};
        \node [circle,draw][right of = a](b){YZ};
        \path (a) -- (b) node[circle,draw] [below, midway, yshift = -2 cm] (d) {Y};
        \node [circle,draw][right of = b](c){XZ};
        \path (b) -- (c) node[circle,draw] [below, midway, yshift = -2 cm] (e) {Z};
        \node [circle, draw][below right of = c,yshift = 0.45 cm, xshift = -1 cm](f) {X};

        \draw (a) -- (d);
        \draw (b) -- (d);

        \draw (b) -- (e);
        \draw (c) -- (e);

        \draw (a) -- (f);
        \draw (c) -- (f);

     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code successfully generates the required output, however, as can be observed, it is a little messy, since I have to manually adjust the distances using xshift and yshift to acquire the desired results. So, I was wondering if there exists a better approach to achieve the same (or yet, better) results.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, *compilable* example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Done !

Comment: @BitRiver I have added a picture without `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`. I hope it is not a problem.

Comment: @BitRiver I see that you've accepted an answer already. It's good to accept answers, but it's sometimes useful to wait a bit of time before accepting since multiple answers can take a little time to appear. In this case you have three good answers. I'm not suggesting that you need to change which one is accepted, but pointing out that you can if you find one of the answers more useful to you.  See [Should we wait a bit before accepting answers?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/209) for some discussion of this.

Comment: @AlanMunn I believe you are correct. I will always keep that on mind from now on.

Answer (score 2):

With a `matrix of nodes` it's also easy to do it.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}        
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, nodes={circle, draw}, 
             column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm] 
{
 XY &   & YZ &   & XZ \\
    & Y &    & Z &    & X \\
};

\draw (A-1-1)--(A-2-6)--(A-1-5);
\draw (A-1-1)--(A-2-2)--(A-1-3);
\draw (A-1-3)--(A-2-4)--(A-1-5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With tkz-graph, this kind of graphs are easy to  create

```
   \documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
   \usepackage{tkz-graph}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \SetGraphUnit{4}
      \Vertices[x=0,y=2]{line}{XY,YZ,XZ}
      \Vertices[x=2,y=0]{line}{Y,Z,X}
      \Edges(XY,Y,YZ,Z,XZ,X,XY)
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

You add           `\GraphInit[vstyle=Shade]`and you get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]
\node [circle,draw](xy){XY};
\node [circle,draw][below right of = xy](y){Y};
\node [circle,draw][above right of = y](yz){YZ};
\node [circle,draw][below right of = yz](z){Z};
\node [circle,draw][above right of = z](xz){XZ};
\node [circle,draw][below right of = xz](x){X};

\draw (xy) -- (x);
\draw (xy) -- (y);
\draw (y) -- (yz);
\draw (yz) -- (z);
\draw (z) -- (xz);
\draw (xz) -- (x);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I used below right and above right to draw all the nodes, then I connected them.

By the way, I used better node ids (instead of a, b, c...). This looks much clearer.